# Bootstrap Image Gallery lightbox displaying all images from multiple galleries. Want only specific gallery images displayed

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have integrated the Bootstrap Image Gallery (http://blueimp.github.io/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/) on my site partially successfully, however if I have multiple galleries on a page/post when the images are clicked and lightbox opens the carousel cycles through all the images of every gallery. What I would like is for the lightbox to just cycle through the images of the specific gallery that is clicked.

I can achieve what I want by hard coding the HTML for each gallery and setting the appropriate IDs etc, but I want to use the Wordpress gallery widget to add the galleries and for the light box to just work.

I am using roots framework base theme on Wordpress and have played around with the gallery.php file but to no avail. In the `gallery.php` file there is a `roots_gallery` function and part of that function creates a div class ID based on the post ID for the gallery, and then also a unique number ID which is specific to that gallery. The line of code from the `gallery.php` file is as below:

```
$unique = (get_query_var('page')) ? $instance . '-p' . get_query_var('page'): $instance;
$output = '<div class="gallery gallery-' . $id . '-' . $unique . '">';
```

In the same `gallery.php` file there is a `roots_attachment_link_class` function which uses the `str_replace` function to alter the  tag of each gallery image to add a thumbnail class as below:

```
function roots_attachment_link_class($html) {
  $postid = get_the_ID();
  $html = str_replace('<a', '<a class="thumbnail img-thumbnail"', $html);
  return $html;
}
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_link', 'roots_attachment_link_class', 10, 1);
```

To achieve what I want I just need to add a `data-gallery` attribute to the above `str_replace` function which corresponds to the same gallery ID, like so:

```
$html = str_replace('<a', '<a class="thumbnail img-thumbnail" data-gallery=".blueimp-gallery-[gallery ID], $html);
```

I can get the first part of the gallery ID no problem by using:

```
$id = get_the_ID();
```

But I cannot get the `$unique` ID part which is created in the `roots_gallery` function. I have tried this:

```
  $id = get_the_ID();
  static $instance = 0;
  $instance++;
  $unique = (get_query_var('page')) ? $instance . '-p' . get_query_var('page'): $instance;

  $html = str_replace('<a', '<a class="thumbnail img-thumbnail" data-gallery=".blueimp-gallery-' .$id . '-' . $unique . '"', $html);
  return $html;
```

The `$instance` part is used in the `roots_gallery` function, but here it gives a unique ID to every image meaning that the lightbox shows just that one image.

I'm not expert php coder so this could be basic stuff but i've been scratching my head for a while now so any help is greatly appreciated. I can provide the full `gallery.php` file if necessary.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I have cracked it, thanks to cfx for pointing me in the right direction. Fairly simple really but in my limited coding experience I have tended to stay clear of global variables, but that's what I needed here.

I made the `$unique` variable global in the `roots_gallery` function and then referenced it in the `roots_attachment_link_class()` function.

In `roots_gallery`:

```
global $unique; 
$unique = (get_query_var('page')) ? $instance . '-p' . get_query_var('page'): $instance;
```

In `roots_attachment_link_class()`:

```
global $unique;

$html = str_replace('<a', '<a class="thumbnail img-thumbnail" data-gallery=".blueimp-gallery-' .$id . '-' . $unique . '"', $html);
return $html;
```

Seems to be working as I want so far anyway.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Check out PHP's manual on [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). You may have some luck saving `$instance` into a new global variable which you can then reference inside `roots_attachment_link_class()` in the anchor markup.